# USB Android Debbugging, I've tried everything I can think of

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I've been struggling for the past 3 days with trying to get started with USB debugging for android apps. Currently, my phone is not being recognized by my computer at all. Here is what I have already done/tried:

-Enable USB debugging on phone - check

-Restarted all devices - way too many times check

-When I check device manager to update drivers etc, my device doesn't show up under 'Other Devices' or anything related to the phone but instead under 'Human Interface Devices'

-And when I try to update the drivers from there, it will not work, telling me that the drivers are already at the highest.

-When my phone is plugged into my computer, it charges but even the file explorer does not see that it is connected, I have no way to view the phone.

-I have tried 3 different brands of usb/micro-usb cords to see if that was the problem

-I have updated all drivers for my computer

I've tried many many other obscure things as well but if anyone has any ideas please please let me know!

Running an LG-D631 Vista

Comment: Does the phone think it is connected? When it does, there's an "ongoing" notification saying "USB debugging connected".

Comment: You should look directly on LG's website for drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with my LG Nexus 4 not being recognised when I connected it to my laptop and in the end this solved the problem for me...

On your mobile:

1. Go to Settings > Storage > USB Computer Condition (Menu option from Storage Screen)
2. Change from Media Device (MTP) to Camera (PTP)

After that it was recognised without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I always had these problems with my old phone.
Most of the times this helped:

1. Go to Device Manager right click and choose update driver software
2. Choose to search for drivers on your pc
3. Click Search and go choose: "Android SDK Path"\extras\google\usb_driver

If that doesnt help, repeat step 1 and 2 and press "choose from list". Then choose Medium and choose "Android SDK Path"\extras\google\usb_driver\android.winusb.inf. Then you should be able to choose "Android ADB Interface". Click next and press yes and it should install that driver.

Hope this helps you, cause i know how frustrating those problems can be

Comment: You should add the link for Android SDK, not everybody knows where to get it.